# pasar variable de android studio a mi archivo php

Tags: php, mysql, android-studio

`

```html
btnbuscar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mostrarcargasdespachos("http://192.168.100.6:8080/bd_quesillera/prueba.php");
            }
        });
```

`buen dia para todos espero me puedan ayudar con un problema que tengo. Quiero pasar una variable que contiene una fecha a mi archivo php.

tengo un texview que contiene una fecha lo que quiero es lo siguiente.

php
obtenervariablefecha= variabledeandroid:

$consulta="SELECT (SELECT SUM(cantidad) FROM entradaqueso where  fehcha=variabledeandroid) AS cantidadentrada ...

```html
private void mostrarcargasdespachos(String URL){
        JsonArrayRequest JsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                JSONObject JsonObject = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    try {
                        JsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        tvCantcarga.setText(JsonObject.getString("cantidadentrada"));
                        tvCantdespachos.setText(JsonObject.getString("cantidadsalida"));
                        tvCosto.setText(JsonObject.getString("totalentrada"));
                        tvValor.setText(JsonObject.getString("totalsalida"));
                        tvCostocompra.setText(JsonObject.getString("costo"));

                        int cantentrada = Integer.parseInt(tvCantcarga.getText().toString());
                        int cantsalida = Integer.parseInt(tvCantdespachos.getText().toString());
                        int resultado=cantentrada-cantsalida;
                        tvPerdidakg.setText(""+resultado);

                        int costcompra = Integer.parseInt(tvCostocompra.getText().toString());
                        int perdidacost = resultado*costcompra;
                        tvPerdiacosto.setText(""+perdidacost);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No existe",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        RequestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        RequestQueue.add(JsonArrayRequest);
    }
```

php

solo quiero obtener esa variable el resto ya lo tengo bien. muchas gracias por su atención y espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Como lees la variable desde la pagina php?

Comment: PHP se ejecuta en un servidor, ¿cómo accedes a dicho servidor desde Android (API, Servicio Web, etc) y qué herramienta usas para consultar al servidor?

Comment: muchas gracias por sus respuestas, si lo que pasa es que tengo una aplicación creada en android estudio y una base de datos de mysq. simplemente paso mis datos por medio de http client a mi archivo php. los archivos estan alojados en la carpeta htdocs ahi están mis archivos php. envio mis datos por medio de  JsonObject ya puedo accder y obtener respuestas de mi servidor solo deseo es pasar una variable de mi aplicacion android a mi sentencia sql en mi archivo php para poder hacer una condicion con dicha variable.

Comment: La herramienta que estás usando (en Android) debe tener un modo de pasar datos. ¿Has investigado algo al respecto? ¿qué código estás usando para intentarlo? ¿qué errores/problemas tienes sobre ese código? Sin algo concreto no podemos ayudarte, porque no sabemos qué estás usando. Android tiene Volley, Async Task y multitud de otras herramientas para hacer esto, muéstranos cuál estás usando y qué código has escrito.

Comment: Buen dia mira como puedes ver hago uso de Volley para hacer la comunicación de mis datos de android estudio a mi web service. ahi adjunte mi código muchas gracias por tu ayuda.